# If a person has lockjaw, what disease is he or she suffering from?

Tags: first-aid

Many times I have seen that a persons mouth is forced shut due to the locking of the jaw muscles. You need to apply a lot of force in order to open the mouth.

The cause is a disease that is very dangerous. So I like to know more about this disease.

Comment: There are several conditions with this name. I asume you mean this one: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trismus.
Reading the article, I think you are refering to Tetanus.

Comment: What has your research found so far?

Comment: I am trying to figure out why a decreased mouth opening length would either be considered very dangerous or fall under first-aid, and I‘m really unsure what you want from us...

Comment: This question is unclear since lock jaw normally refers to tetanus.

Comment: Thanks for the share. but lockjaw and tetanus. I don't really get the connection here. Am I the one who doesn't understand this?

Comment: People suffering from epilepsy may have locked jaws during seizures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is unclear. But I (and with me some others) think you are referring to [Tetanus](https://www.healthline.com/health/tetanus).

Tetanus is caused by Clostridium tetani, bacteria found in street dirt and animal dung (for example horse dung). The bacteria enters the wound through a dirty wound (for example a bike accident). It can be cured by a Tetanus vaccination that must be appllied in a few days.

The vaccination last for 10 to 15 years but is sometimes renewed within 7 years. If the victim is not vaccinated the disease can be deadly. One of the symptoms is muscle stiffness often started with the jaw muscles hence the name lock jaw.